# How to know if vim/neovim is focused in tmux when opened?

Tags: neovim

The autocmd events `FocusGained` and `FocusLost` work when switching focus between tmux panes. However, I want to know if vim is focused when it's first opened, I'd like to not run some things if that's the case, such as displaying a message only in the focused vim session.

If you're wondering how that can happen, the tmux session manager [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) can open several panes with vim when restoring sessions.

I am using neovim, and the tmux option `set -g focus-events on`